# Chrome Javascript Debugger equivalent of Python list (l)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In pdb (python debugger), one of the first things I do is type `l` or `list` to print the current line, and 5 lines above and below. This refreshes one of the variable names, and gives context on what one is working on, rather than a blank white console.

In Chrome, you has has to look at the console, then mouse over to source, then mouse back to console. I find its very slow switching back and forth. I don't have a large screen to have 2 dev tabs and webpage in view.

Is there a way to print a few lines of source code when the debugger enters a breakpoint?

Ok will I will use the drawer (even though I was not keen), seems like there is no equivalent, a lot of menu noise:
[image]

Comment: You can open the Console as a drawer on the Source tab.

Comment: "I don't have a large screen to have 2 dev tabs and webpage in view.", i.e. I don't have real estate space to see both.

Comment: You don't need two dev tabs. Just open the Console drawer at the bottom of the Source tab.

Comment: Click on the menu at the top right of the Sources tab, and select "Show console drawer". Or press the Escape key to toggle it.

Comment: Yes, and pretty much all I see is menus and have no working space, when I do that.

Comment: You can drag the divider to change the amount of space used for the console and source. So if you only need to see 10 lines around the current line, shrink the source panel and increase the console panel.

Comment: You can `inspect(yourFunction)` to jump to it from the console to the elements tab and then jump back to the console (control+` or whatever it's mapped to in your system)